# UPS Tracking On Google Sheet returns Imported content is empty

Tags: google-sheets

Returns - content is empty

```
=Index(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="&A2,"//*[@id='tt_spStatus']"),1)
```

All the different variations I have tried yield no response. Uk based UPS tracking. I have tried different xPaths to no avail.

This returns content but nothing I understand.

```
=Index(IMPORTXML("https://www.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?loc=en_GB&tracknum="&A2&"&requester=WT/trackdetails","html"),1)
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet ?

Comment: It's a blank sheet with a single tracking number....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function in script editor:

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

source for function: https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/

This formula will output transit status in your cell:

```
=IMPORTJSON(join("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/ups/",A1),"activities/0/details")
```

I don't need the other details, so I made another cell that has a link to the ups tracking page if any other users need more information:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum="&A1&"&requester=WT/trackdetails"",A1:A)")
```

Comment: This is amazing, I couldn't figure out the Json output but the function provided works a treat. Thank you very much. When generating the links I used this to make it more user friendly to read. `={"Tracking links";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,(HYPERLINK(("https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_GB&tracknum="&A2:AH&"&requester=WT/trackdetails"),A2:A))))}` With the import Json formula I added `=IF(ISBLANK($A2), , IMPORTJSON(join("","shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/ups/…))` to ignore blanks and improve the speed over a large sheet.

Comment: In addition I tried this. `={"Current Status";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A2:A), , IMPORTJSON(join("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/ups/",$A2:A),"activities/0/details"))}` to process column as an array. But it returns all empty responses. This could be todo with the fact `"http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/ups/",$A2:A` can only take a single input.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned ISBLANK, I added a check for that after posting, but never updated.  It really cleans up the sheets.

Comment: Does this API still work?  I'm getting `Error getting data` . I changed the return to err.toString and got `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it work with USPS. However for UPS the json return is:
{"error":"Invalid Access License number"}

I dont know if there is any other solution except using UPS API that requires Access License number.

Answer (score 0):

JSON for UPS stopped working for a while. Right now I'm using this formula, maybe someone is still looking for it.

```
=if(H8>0, mid(index(IMPORTXML("https://www.theupsstore.ca/track/"&H8,"//*[@class='table-striped table-responsive feature-table table']"),1,1),79,120),"")
```